# Nextjs, react and TypeScript: prop type missing on FC using getInitialProps when used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a very basic React and Nextjs project built in TypeScript. I'm currently building this project from scratch to understand Nextjs better, I'm already quite proficient with TypeScript and React.

I have a simple Clock component built like below, and as per the [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#typescript).

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

type Props = {
    isoTime: string
}

const Clock: NextPage<Props> = ({ isoTime }: Props) => {
    return <p>{isoTime}</p>;
}

Clock.getInitialProps = async () => {
    return {
        isoTime: new Date().toISOString()
    };
};

export default Clock;
```

No problems here, however when I try and use this component elsewhere, for example in my app component...

```
import React from 'react';
import Clock from './clock/Clock';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Clock />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I get the TypeScript error `Property 'isoTime' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'.` If I add a `{/*@ts-ignore*/}` above the error it compiles and works as expected, however I shouldn't have to remove typesafety just to get this to compile. How can I get TypeScript to pick up the props coming from getInitialProps?

Comment: `getInitialProps` is not for components. It's only for pages. Components and pages are very different in NextJS.

Comment: I haven't read that anywhere, and it does work - it's just a tsc error. Perhaps I need to return a type diffferent to NextPage<Props>?

Comment: read this @JamesMorrison https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461803/next-js-componentwillmount-vs-getinitialprops#:~:text=GetInitialProps%20is%20a%20usually%20an,in%20pages%20not%20in%20components.

Comment: It's also mentioned in the official docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#caveats.

Answer (score -1):

According to nextJS documentation the put it as a optional props

```
interface Props {
  userAgent?: string;
}

const Page: NextPage<Props> = ({ userAgent }) => (
  <main>Your user agent: {userAgent}</main>
)

Page.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const userAgent = req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
  return { userAgent }
}

export default Page
```

From you code it will be like this

```
type Props = {
    isoTime?: string
}
```

Comment: I can't just mark all server side props as optional when they're not, that also removes typesafety

Comment: try to console inside clock component and console as well as in getInitialProps function and see which console is running first.